# Syntax Error when deploying Firebase cloud function V2

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Here is the code

```
import {logger} from 'firebase-functions/v2';
import {getDatabase} from 'firebase-admin/database';
import {onSchedule} from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler";

import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin/app";


const app = initializeApp();
const database = getDatabase(app);

exports.scheduledfunction = onSchedule("* * * * *", async (event) => {
    // Fetch all user details.
    logger.log('test');
});
```

And here is the error:

> Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may
> have a syntax or runtime error

2 problems:

1. I don't know where to look for more details about the error which make it very difficult to fix. Since it's a syntax error, I find nothing in the console logs. Maybe it's burried somewhere there.
2. What is the syntax problem with this code?

And here is the functions json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Mixed `import` and `require()`? What's that about?

Comment: Ok I updated the code with import. You are right about that thanks. But it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: You've still got one `require()`. What command are you running that generates the error? If it references a script in `package.json`, please also include the details

Comment: I believe your function should consist out of lowercase characters only

Comment: Nope. Won't help.

Comment: Phil, I updated the code with removing the require. The command I run is : "firebase deploy --only functions. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in order to use V2 functions with working code, I had to specifically use const/require syntax.

Here is proof of concept working v2code:

```
const {logger} = require('firebase-functions/v2');
const {onSchedule} = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getDatabase} = require('firebase-admin/database');


const app = initializeApp();
const database = getDatabase(app);
// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

// exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
//   logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

exports.minutecandidates = onSchedule({
        schedule: "* * * * *",
        minInstances: 1,
        maxInstances: 1,
        // include other options here from SchedulerOptions or GlobalOptions
    },
    async (context) => {
        logger.log("test");
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Was banging my head against this for a while!